# Recreating the Tacx Neo Smart Bike

Tags: turbo-trainer, indoor

I love the soon to be released [Tacx Neo Smart Bike](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2018/07/tacx-neo-bike-smart-first-ride-and-final-specs.html) for its seatpost and handlebar adjustability which will hopefully make it super easy for my wife and me to share a single indoor training bike.

Thing is, I already have a Tacx Neo and would like to see if I can rig up something similar by outfitting an existing bike frame with a handlebar and a seatpost that are both just as easily adjustable. I've checked with Tacx and as at Jul 2018 they are not planning to offer any trade-ins.

I figure that the seatpost is an easier fix, since I could have 2 seatposts with a QR clamp to allow fast switching. I'm not so sure about the handlebars.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could use an adjustable handlerbar stem designed for use in bike fittings (such as [this](https://purelycustomfit.com/product/bicycle-sizing-stem/) for instance), although that's probably not the most cost effective option.

Comment: One trainer each?  You can race together on Zwift.